Mount ext4 as a drive letter to Windows via WSL 2
Simply the question is:
Is there a way to map \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wsl\PHYSICALDRIVE0 as a network drive (assign a Windows drive letter to it)?
In Windows 10, I'm using WSL 2.
I tried net use, but it asks me for username and password and I gave it the Ubuntu username and password, but it didn't work.

Oh yes! Instead of using "net use" I may use subst command as follows:
subst z: \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wsl\PHYSICALDRIVE0

This should be done after the following command as super user:
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0


Works great but only for that terminal session. Wish this could apply globally (i.e, to File Explorer as well)

This should work globally!
